.NET / C#: How to ignore GenerateDocumentationFile for source generated .g.cs files by packages
My .csproj file uses
<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>

to indicate that we will be auto-generating documentation.
A given package I use creates loads of code using source generators. However, during compilation it raises dozens of warnings.
How to selectively ignore *.g.cs from this analysis?
Important: because it's not me that is generating the code, I cannot add // <auto-generated/> or other stuff into the code.

This question is similar to: Code analysis warnings in generated code (like migrations) - Visual Studio (C#). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

the question mentioned deals with the code generated by the dev. My question focus in the code generated by 3rd party (packages), so I cannot add // <auto-generated/> of interfere with the process
